# RestEasy, how to prevent marshalling of JAXB annotated POJOs to and from JSON

Tags: json, jaxb, jax-rs, marshalling, resteasy

I started with a service that consumes and produces output in JSON. I use the *resteasy-jackson-provider* for (de)marshalling which takes its information from the class description. After a while I was asked to add XML as MediaType. So I annotated my DTOs with JAXB annotations and added the *resteasy-jaxb-provider*. As a result, I observed that the produced JSON output derives from the JAXB annotations which differs from the original format.

I am on RestEasy Version 3.0.4. As described I use the following providers

1. *resteasy-jackson-provider*
2. *resteasy-axb-provider*.
3. *resteasy-jettison-provider*, because I integrated RestEasy into Spring and this provider is a transitive dependency.

I got aware of the problem when I

1. used `XmlElementWrapper` for lists and when
2. I wrote a custom `XmlAdapter` which serializes a complex data structure `Map<String, List<String>>`. Requests with XML MediaType are fine. Requests with JSON MediaType cause an exception. Jackson seems to exploit the `XmlAdapter` for further information. This was not the case before. Jackson was able to marshall the Map without the JAXB annotations.

   org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "customer" (Class x.y.z.OptionalParametersMapType), not marked as ignorable
    at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@77119553; line: 1, column: 131] (through reference chain: x.y.z.Request["optional"]->x.y.zOptionalParametersMapType["customer"]
   )
           at org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:53)
           at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.unknownFieldException(StdDeserializationContext.java:267)
           at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.reportUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:673)
           at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:659)
           at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializer.java:1365)
           at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer._handleUnknown(BeanDeserializer.java:725)
           at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:703)
           at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
           at org.codehaus.jackson.xc.XmlAdapterJsonDeserializer.deserialize(XmlAdapterJsonDeserializer.java:59)
           at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:299)
           at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:579)
           at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:697)
           at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
           at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2704)
           at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1315)
           at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:419)

So, how can I prevent RestEasy from using the JAXB annotations for marshalling to and from JSON?

Here is the request class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "domainRecommendationRequest")
public class Request {

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(OptionalParametersXmlAdapter.class)
    private Map<String, List<String>> optional = new HashMap<>();

}
```

Here is the XmlAdapter:

```
@Override
public class OptionalParametersXmlAdapter extends XmlAdapter<OptionalParametersMapType, Map<String, List<String>>> {

    public OptionalParametersMapType marshal(Map<String, List<String>> v) throws Exception {
        OptionalParametersMapType result = new OptionalParametersMapType();
        List<OptionalParameterItemType> optionalParameterItemTypes = new ArrayList<>();

        Set<String> keySet = v.keySet();

        for (String parameterName : keySet) {
            OptionalParameterItemType item = new OptionalParameterItemType();
            item.name = parameterName;
            item.values = v.get(parameterName);
            optionalParameterItemTypes.add(item);
        }

        result.parameter = optionalParameterItemTypes;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Here is the wrapper for the map:

```
public class OptionalParametersMapType {
    public List<OptionalParameterItemType> parameter = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Here is the actual map entry item:

```
public class OptionalParameterItemType {

    @XmlAttribute
    public String name;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "values")
    @XmlElement(name = "value")
    public List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

This is what I expect in the JSON request:

```
{"optional":{"customer":["Mike"]}}
```

As you can see, I do intend to have a different format in XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `resteasy-jackson-provider` depends on `jackson-module-jaxb-annotations`, which is used to map JAXB annotations/annotated classes to JSON. Now in a normal explicit use of `ObjectMapper`, in order to make use of this module, we would need to explicitly register this module like (See [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations))

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JaxbAnnotationModule module = new JaxbAnnotationModule();
objectMapper.registerModule(module);

-- OR --

AnnotationIntrospector introspector = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector();
objectMapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(introspector);
```

That being said, it *appears* (not confirmed with any facts, but looks probable) that when the `ObjectMapper` is being created for your serialization, when the JAXB annotations are noticed, the module is automatically registered.

I don't know of any possible annotations we can use to stop this, but one way to solve this problem is to create a `ContextResolver` for the `ObjectMapper`, where we don't register the JAXB module.

```
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperContextResolver 
                  implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return new ObjectMapper();
    }  
}
```

Once we register that with our JAX-RS application, it will be the context resolver used to get the `ObjectMapper`. We could configure the `ObjectMapper` further, but this is just an example. Test it and it works as expected.